# How to get base class object from closed constructed class in C#

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, compiler-errors

Just another small C# training app, and just another Compilation Error, but it cannot just go away from me...  I am just wondering, what I am doing wrong here:

```
public abstract class Material
{

}

public abstract class Cloth<T> where T:Material
{
    public T Prop { get; set; }
}

public class Cotton : Material
{

}

public class Dress<T> : Cloth<T> where T : Material
{

}

public class Test
{
    private Cloth<Material> cloth;

    public Test()
    {
        /* below won't compile */
        cloth = new Dress<Cotton>();
    }
}
```

I want to get the base class object from a closed constructed class. Anyone ?

When trying to compile I get the error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type Dress<Cotton> to Cloth<Material>
```

Comment: Downvote for not thinking like a programmer and at the very least providing the compile error message.

Comment: Well, seems like since it's my very first post at StackOverflow I did not meet your high expectations oh Master ;) Error message added.

Comment: I appreciate that, but for future reference, I don't believe providing details about the error you want help with is specific to stackoverflow.

Comment: @JonathanWood BTW in this edge case everyone aware about how generics work could be able to solve the issue without the compiler error. But you're right, the more detail the OP provides, easier will be fixing the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve is called **covariance** ([see the following article for samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx)).

Unfortunately, there's no variance support for classes: it's restricted to interfaces and delegates.

Thus and alternatively, you might design an interface called `ICloth<T>` with `T` covariant:

```
public interface ICloth<out T>
{
    T Prop { get; set; }
}
```

And implement it in any of your possible cloths, including `Cloth<T>`.

Now type `cloth` as `ICloth<T>` and your assignment should work (i.e. `cloth = new Dress<Cotton>();`), because `Dress<Cotton>` is `ICloth<out T>`, which is an interface with a `T` covariant generic parameter.

Learn more about generic interface with variance [in the following article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233059.aspx).

Comment: Works like a charm (almost - you have to remove setter from T Prop in ICloth). Thank you